# Could not dind main class: XXXXX .the program will exit

Tags: double, minecraft

MM hey ^_^
i was following this post [HERE](http://words-from-scarystuff.blogspot.com/2011/09/minecraft-and-mods.html) and when opening .bat file an error says :
could not dind main class: net.minecraft.LauncherFrame.the program will exit.
any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably paste the actual .bat file you used, but I believe that method no longer works with starting the minecraft launcher executable.

Comment: i used exactly the same one in the tutorial :(

Comment: That would be why, it's a bit outdated.

Comment: mm see this topic
http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/k7mmv/how_to_run_multiple_versions_of_minecraft/

Comment: some one says 
"As a developer i'd prefer to have multiple minecraft-directories in the appdata folder and change their name to .minecraft with a batchfile instead of changing the appdata-variable, even if it doesn't effect anything. It wouldn't be portable anymore though.."
would you just explain what did he said ??

Comment: re: the reddit topic. That was a year ago, and it's still outdated.

The comment sounds like gibberish to me. As far as I understand, you can't have multiple of the same directory name in a location, and there's no reason to edit window's environment variables.

Comment: this means that there is no way to create many other minecraft in the same pc :(
thx 4 help

Comment: You can launch multiple instances, I'm not sure you really need multiple directories for anything at all.